# Distributing a borrow across a tuple

Tags: rust, tuples, borrow-checker

Put simply: Is there any way to go from the tuple `(&x, &y)` to the tuple `&(x, y)`? Presumably where the second tuple has a borrow equivalent to the shorter of the two lifetimes between `x` and `y`. I've seen examples where `ref` can be used to extract a reference from a tuple (so `&(x, y)` to `&x` and `&y`), but I can't find any mention of going the other way.

Thanks!